# Site that sells GPL code has extra terms that say I can't resell it. Is this legal?

Tags: gpl

I found a website which sells a WordPress theme licensed under GPL that has this in their terms on the checkout page:

> Our products are licensed under the GNU General Public License (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) version 2.0 or later.
>
> You may not provide access to the installation of our products as a hosting service provider or a reseller, and you may not provide to others as part of a “Software As-a-Service” (SaaS). You may not bundle it and resell it as a commercial, off the shelf, license or product.

Is this legal? I thought that the GPL gives you the right to resell and host it as a SaaS if you desire so.
Can I be legally bound to their terms and conditions and their GPL at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

It's legal - assuming they're the sole rightsholder, they may make their code available on any terms they choose - but it's completely ineffective.  You may elect to take it under [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html) (as it says "*GPLv2 or later*") then, under the provision of s7 that says

> If the Program as you received it, or any part of it, contains a notice stating that it is governed by this License along with a term that is a further restriction, you may remove that term.

you may remove the other restrictions they placed on it, and use it under the normal terms of GPLv3.

Comment: And they may then ban you from their store, but it doesn't matter because you already have the code.

Comment: Having just found this; I would have interpreted the extra term applies only to their pre-distributed binary and not to the source.